# Slop parsing command line arguments with multiple inputs per argument option in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, command-line-interface

I am using Slop in ruby to parse the input arguments:

```
slop_opts = Slop.parse(ARGV.map(&:strip)) do |o|                                
  o.string '--test1', 'explain test1'                             
  o.string '--test2', 'explain test2'                                      
  o.on '--help' do                                                              
    puts o                                                                      
    exit                                                                        
  end                                                                           
end                                                                             
                                                                                
slop_opts.to_hash
```

And I need that `test2` could include several options:
e.g.

```
ruby this_script.rb --test1 one_arg --test2 first_arg second_arg
```

One constraint that I have is that I need first_arg and second_arg to be 2 different inputs, so I can't just get them from splitting on `,` (or similar) an input string like `first_arg,second_arg`.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `--test2` an [Array argument](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop#arrays). Set the delimiter to `nil` to disable splitting the input.

```
slop_opts = Slop.parse(ARGV.map(&:strip)) do |o|                                
  o.string '--test1', 'explain test1'                             
  o.array '--test2', 'explain test2', delimiter: nil                                  
  o.on '--help' do                                                              
    puts o                                                                      
    exit                                                                        
  end                                                                           
end
```

Then each input gets its own `--test2`.

```
ruby this_script.rb --test1 one_arg --test2 first_arg --test2 second_arg
```